# How do you add a scroll bar to a div?

Tags: css, scroll, popup

I have a popup that displays some results, and I want a scroll bar to be display since the results are being cutt off (and I don't want the popup to be too long).

Answer (score 167):

You need to add `style="overflow-y:scroll;"` to the div tag. (This will force a scrollbar on the vertical).

If you only want a scrollbar when needed, just do `overflow-y:auto;`

Comment: Would the div being positioned absolutely prevent the scrollbar from working?

Comment: @DavidSpector just tested it, it still works for an absolutely positioned div. https://jsfiddle.net/Ld3mb1y0/

Answer (score 31):

Css class to have a nice Div with scroll

```
.DivToScroll{   
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
    color: #3B3C3E;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -1px;
    padding: 10px 7px 5px;
}

.DivWithScroll{
    height:120px;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why there are two divs here. Is it important?

Answer (score 26):

to add scroll u need to define **max-height** of your div and then add **overflow-y**

so do something like this

```
.my_scroll_div{
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the same behavior as overflow-y: hidden. What could be wrong?

Comment: @DavidSpector maybe CSS is overwritten some where. try to add `!important` it end  then try `.my_scroll_div{
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    max-height: 100px !important;
}`

Answer (score 15):

If you want to add a scroll bar using jquery the following will work.  If your div had a id of 'mydiv' you could us the following jquery id selector with css property:

```
jQuery('#mydiv').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
```

Comment: It is correct, where need to add it dinamically with jquery. It works for me. Thanks

Comment: @Chaki_Black great point. I added a similar answer to a question about dynamic scroll on a div here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36314963/2512022)

Comment: This method is a bit outdated, even if dynamic selection is required. Modern DOM have more or less deprecated jQuery. See https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/selectors/ or any number of similar articles for supplemental information.

Answer (score 9):

```
<div class="scrollingDiv">foo</div> 

div.scrollingDiv
{
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: @webdestroya: It will only add scrolling to divs that have the classname of "scrollingDiv". That could be as few as 1, or even 0, or as many as all the divs the designer wishes to have scrollbars.

Comment: @webdestroya: I didn't touch it. And the post didn't show as being edited when I commented. W/e.

Comment: @Robusto - I think he was referring that I edited it. Because I did edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: @Robusto - Yea, I meant gmcalab edited it. Originally it just said `div` in the spec, it didn't have the class. Either way, I removed my comment because it is now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

```
<head>
<style>
div.scroll
{
background-color:#00FFFF;
width:40%;
height:200PX;
FLOAT: left;
margin-left: 5%;
padding: 1%;
overflow:scroll;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>



<div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better       control of the layout. The default value is visible.better control of the layout. The default value is visible.better control of the layout. The default value is visible.better control of the layout. The default value is visible.better control of the layout. The default value is visible.better control of the layout. The default value is visible.better </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CSS file, you can define a call for the `<div>` element and assign the `overflow: auto` CSS property.

In the HTML file: `<div class="container">`

In the CSS file you put:

```
.container{
    overflow: "auto";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve a scroller on a div, here find a simple `easy way` one with `an easy explanation`.

```
.my_scroll_div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100px; 
}
```

Here is a bit explanation of the above code.

> overflow-y: auto;

The `overflow-y` property of CSS adds a scroller when needed, If we want to add the scroller after a specific height (e.g 100px in our case)
Then,

> max-height: 100px;

We add the `max-height` property of CSS so for example to add a scroller after `100px` of height then `max-height: 100px;` is used.

I hope this explanation is helpful in clearing the concepts as well.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.scroll {
            max-height: 50px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="scroll">
        You can use the overflow property when you want to have better
        control of the layout. The default value is visible.better control
        of the layout. The default value is visible.better control of the
        layout. The default value is visible.better control of the layout.
        The default value is visible.better control of the layout. The
        default value is visible.better control of the layout. The default
        value is visible.better
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```