# How to add scroll bar dynamically in div?

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, scrollbar

Hi I need to add a Scroll bar dynamically. I tried http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow, but its not working. Anybody kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set height and width properties for it to work. The scroll will appear only after the specified height &/or width size is exceeded. Depending on which way (Vertical/ Horizontal scroll) you want it to scroll, set the properties accordingly

Comment: i set width and height also but its not working.i need the scroll bar for height

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery to add a scroll bar dynamically to a div. The code to do this is exactly the same as the code I used in another Answer of mine here (code is also below):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25572315/2512022

```
jQuery('#mydiv').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
```