# A scroll bar to a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've got a DIV which is supposed to hold multiple DIVs inside it. How can I set a scroll bar to a DIV?

```
<div id="container"> //need a scroller to this div
<div id="subcontainer1"></div>//created dynamically
<div id="subcontainer2"></div>//created dynamically
<div id="subcontainer3"></div>//created dynamically
more created dynamically....
</div>
```

Comment: give it a fixed height and set `overflow:auto;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2836830/1083946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a fixed height using the `height` property and then set `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll`

Here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vinith98/oyug02xz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your stylesheet `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto`

```
#container{
overflow:auto;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper-div {
      overflow: auto;
      width: 12%;
      height: 80%;
}
```

Use the above class(.wrapper-div) for the div for which you want to have scroll bars. specify width and height.